# My comments are being posted when I move to another window...

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I start writing a comment... then I might move to another window to do something... time passes... I do many things in many windows...  Then I come back to complete my **askubuntu** comment...  and it has been **posted** (and I'm not the one who posted it!)

This is becoming a chronic problem...   Some of these un-edited comments are definitely not ready for general viewing... and I can't re-edit them because of the comment-edit timeout (which I don't quite know the details of yet)...

Has anyone else experienced this? ...

I've noticed that some general settings interact badly with some aspects of other programs.
eg. When Assistive Technologies "*Mouse Locate Pointer by pressing CtrL*" is enabled, it prevents me from using Ctrl+C to copy a filename when in "*Nautilus filename-Rename (F2)**
... maybe it is something along this line?

Comment: I have experienced a similar problem. Do you use GNOME Do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this.

However, note that comments will submit if the comment box has focus and <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff...   I do  make the occasional "Oh-no! where did that go?" mistake, but this one just feels different to me... I disabled the (Windows) Recycle Bin, the day it was invented, so I tend to be pretty careful... I'll just keep an eye on it... If this is not a known issue, it is almost certainly something local.. like me? maybe :(  ... By the way, I loved every epoisode of the IT Conversations podcasts with Joel...